# Woocommerce variations for all attributes except one

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to define a priority order for getting price from variations ?

I explain :

I have a product with an attribute who have 40+ values

I have another attribute with 3 values

eg :

- **Attribute 1** => 40+ values (foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4...)
- **Attribute 2** => 3 values (bar1, bar2, bar3)

I have created 3 variations, because, the only attribute that change price is the **Attribute 2**.

I have this configuration for variations :

- **All attributes 1** + **value of attribute 2 : bar1**
- **All attributes 1** + **value of attribute 2 : bar2**
- **All attributes 1** + **value of attribute 2 : bar3**

I need to add another variation :

- **Attribute 1 value : foo3** + **Attribute 2 value : bar1**

But this variation is overriden by the variation : **All attributes 1** + **attribute 2 value : bar1**, the price shown is the not correct.

I can create all possible variations, but it's not very convenient...

There is a tip or a plugin to do that ? Or a way to configure, All attributes, except this value...

Thanks